# What The Square Brackets are Doing and What is It Referencing (Stylesheet or is It Universal Code Block)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsx

I'm trying to make a image in WordPress into a slider but the person before me has code in the widget box that I'm unsure of. I wanna know what the `[]`is doing and or what language is this in?

I tried to recreate this code in CodePen and I can see what its doing.

```
[av_fullscreen size='extra_large' image_attachment='' animation='slide_up' autoplay='false' interval='5' control_layout='av-control-minimal' perma_caption='aviaTBperma_caption']
  [av_fullscreen_slide slide_type='image' id='1514' position='top center' video='http://' mobile_image='' video_cover='' title='ARE YOU READY FOR SUMMER' custom_title_size='60' custom_content_size='21' caption_pos='caption_bottom' link_apply='button' link='lightbox' link_target='' button_label='SCHEDULE A FREE CONSULTATION' button_color='blue' link1='manually,#quote' link_target1='' button_label2='FREE QUOTE' button_color2='light' link2='manually,http://' link_target2='' font_color='custom' custom_title='#ff0000' custom_content='#ffffff' overlay_opacity='0.5' overlay_color='' overlay_pattern='' overlay_custom_pattern='']
    Best deals of the year on overstockheating & cooling systems!
  [/av_fullscreen_slide]
[/av_fullscreen]
```

Just looking for a description what this is and what its doing. Is it a text slider? Can I remove it ?

Comment: i guess this is a shortcode .https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: It seems to be some internal script language for whatever plugin you are using. If you notices, it tells you that it setting up a full-screen and a slide inside such full-screen. The rest inside the `[]` seems to be properties.

Comment: Thanks guys , that helped me see the format of the code.